# .getElementsByClassName()[] -- what am I not understanding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with HTML, CSS, jQuery, and JavaScript, all on one HTML page. Generally, I trying to figure out for the first time how to access information from the HTML body for use in my JavaScript code.

I want to set a variable in JavaScript equal to the string contained in the data attribute of one of my `<div>` elements.

Can I use `document.getElementsByClassName()[]` in my JavaScript to actually pull the information out of the HTML document? In examples on W3schools and elsewhere, I only see it used to change the value of some HTML element, not to actually use its input. Is there something more fundamental that I'm missing, here?

____here's my more specific code (where `div.onlyOne` is the only div of that class, and has the data-need attribute "string i need"):

```
var myVar = document.getElementsByClassName("onlyOne")[0].getAttribute("data-need")
```

Why will this not store "string i need" into `myVar`?

Comment: what is your html? :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Assuming the HTML is correct, this will work as long as the JavaScript is after the HTML in question or you are waiting for the DOM to load first. Did you place the the JavaScript in the head of the file?

Comment: it's massive, but, basically ... 

<!--the usual stuff-->
<body>
<p>
           <!--... a lot of divs ...-->
           <div id="someid" class="onlyOne" data-need="string i need"></div>
           <!--... a lot more divs ...-->
</p>
</body>

Comment: nateyolles - no, I placed it at the end of the body of the html after all the divs (with tags, o/c), because I thought that would help the document load first. I'm also using jQuery in the same file - should I put them in separate script tags? Or maybe put my javascript inside the $(document).ready function?

Comment: Debug your code. Place a breakpoint on the line in question, and when stopped there, examine the value of `document.getElementsByClassName("onlyOne")`. You will probably find that it is an empty array, because for whatever reason, the element with class `onlyOne` cannot be found, or has not been loaded yet. Taking `document.getElementsByClassName("onlyOne")[0]` will therefore evaluate to `undefined`. trying to call `getAttribute` will then result in a run-time error. Do you see that run-time error in the console? If not, what else do you see? What is the value being assigned to `myvar`/

Answer (score 1):

It works, make sure though, that you run the script after the markup or DOM load, or else the script will not find the element as it has not yet been loaded.

After in markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="onlyOne" data-need="hey there"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = document.getElementsByClassName("onlyOne")[0].getAttribute("data-need");
        alert(myVar);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

DOM load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            var myVar = document.getElementsByClassName("onlyOne")[0].getAttribute("data-need");
            alert(myVar);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="onlyOne" data-need="hey there"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

May I suggest you use `document.querySelector('.onlyOne')` instead in the future. With that you can narrow down the result list in a more efficient way.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Wonderful to know that this works. Our code looks very similar. It must be something else with my setup, but now I know where to look. 

I'm trying to call on the data attribute from within a function, though I don't see how that could make a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much! With your help, I'm finally solving my issues. Do you put "type="text/javascript" in every opening script tag?

Comment: you do not need the type in the script tag for HTML5

Comment: @YungLink Exactly how _gavgrif_ commented

Comment: @YungLink If my answer solved your question, please consider accept it as well

Comment: @torazaburo In mine the script runs after the markup, in the OP's it might not, but of course, I failed to explain that in my answer and will update it right away.

Comment: @torazaburo Hopefully the update made it more clear what to look for if it is not working in OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="onlyOne" data-need="some text">...</div>

var myVar = document.getElementsByClassName("onlyOne")[0].getAttribute("data-need");
alert(myVar);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/howa6w1o/

Answer (score -1):

since you are using jQuery, you can simplify your code to get the contents of the data-attribute: as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var myVar = $(".onlyOne").eq(0).data("need");
})
```

Comment: Or `".onlyOne:first"`.

Comment: Without seeing where he's loading the script, my guess is that he's loading the script in the head, so wrap this to load on document ready.

Comment: I have the scrip placed (loaded?) after the HTML, just before the </body> tag.  It's a jQuery click function that changes the class to .onlyOne in the first place. Does this bring nasty side effects?

Comment: without seeing code - I can't answer for certain, but it should be fine - all you are doing is adding a class to an element and then (assuming that this command is called after the onclick function or as a callback in that function) you are getting the content of the data-attribute of the element you have added the class to.

Comment: Thank you, Sverri, Gavgrif, and Nateyolles. This has been very helpful to help me understand the tools I'm using and it pointed me to my real issues - which are looking more like function scope misuses. You have been very informative -- Thanks, again.

Comment: whomever downvoted this  answer - have the balls to stand up for it and say why you did it.... if it was poor coding then the only way I can improve is if you say what your problem is with my answer. If its cos I went the jQuery way instead of pure JS as in the OP then so be it - there are different ways of doing the same thing - but say it! We are all learning here! and an anonymous unexplained down-vote benefits no-one!

Comment: You are correct, no winners, still, some just do without saying anything, so just leave it be ... +1 from me

Comment: Your answer might or might not work. Most likely, if the OP's code does not work, your code will not either, for the same underlying reason. Therefore, it does not quality as an answer. You need to hypothesize a reason the OP's code does not work, and address that reason, or ask (in comments) for additional information that will help you validate your hypothesis.

Comment: @YungLink What do you mean by "function scope misuses"?

Comment: @torazaburo  - while I respect your greater knowledge, skill and SO contribution, I submit that since the OP's code was as follows: var myVar = document.getElementsByClassName("onlyOne")[0].getAttribute("data-need")  -  and the use of jQuery was indicated that my response provided an alternative to the OP that was valid and appropriate. And therefore qualifies as an answer. There is no requirement to "... hypothesize a reason the OPs code does not work, and address that reason..." to qualify as an answer. An answer can take many forms, including suggesting a new approach to their stated issue.